# How to iterate on TabBar children and how to access TabBar object from Shell in a MAUI application?

Tags: c#, .net, tabs, maui

I have on MainPage of Application a Shell with TabBar with many Tab(s).

I would like to know if there is any possibility to find out in C# code tab titles from TabBar from Shell in a .NET MAUI application

I require to memorize in a model if the tabs are visible or not and would not like the approach to entry them by hand. An iteration on TabBar children would avoid this.

Application is .Net 6 MAUI version.

I tried finding out ways to access TabBar object from Shell but could not find any way in Shell object API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TabBar` is part of the `Shell` so to get to the current shell object you need to use the `Current` property that holds this instance of the Shell. With this you find all the Items in the shell, which is a `ShellItemCollection`, ie TabBar.

```cs
var shell = Shell.Current;  // Active Shell
var tabBar = shell.Items[0]; // The TabBar
var allShellItem = tabBar.Items; // All our Tabs
```

To get all the visable tabs is a bit tricky. But if you look inside the class `ShellItem` you find `GetItems`

```cs
ReadOnlyCollection<ShellSection> IShellItemController.GetItems() => ((ShellSectionCollection)Items).VisibleItemsReadOnly;
```

This is part of `IShellItemController` that `ShellItem`, ie `TabBar`, inherent so we get to use it like this.

```cs
var visableItems = (tabBar as IShellItemController).GetItems();
```

To put it all together and clean it up a bit we can put this in a List that gives us all information about our tabs

```cs
private List<TabBarItemElement> GetCurrentTabBarList()
{
    var tabBarItems = new List<TabBarItemElement>();
    var tabBar = Shell.Current.Items[0];
    var visableItems = (tabBar as IShellItemController).GetItems();
    foreach (ShellSection item in tabBar.Items)
    {
        tabBarItems.Add(new TabBarItemElement
        {
            Title = item.Title,
            Icon = item.Icon,
            IsVisable = visableItems.Contains(item)
        });
    }

    return tabBarItems;
}

private class TabBarItemElement
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ImageSource Icon { get; set; }

    public bool IsVisable { get; set; }
}
```